# Why the "/index" redirect to the UnauthorizedUrl in shiro?

Tags: spring-boot, shiro

I test the shiro with springboot,but no matter what urls like 127.0.0.1:8080/index are redirected to the the UnauthorizedUrl("/error");

Here is my ShiroConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    @Bean(name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor lifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public MyShiroRealm myShiroRealm(){
        MyShiroRealm myShiroRealm = new MyShiroRealm();
        myShiroRealm.setCredentialsMatcher(hashedCredentialsMatcher());
        return myShiroRealm;
    }

    @Bean
    public HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher(){
        HashedCredentialsMatcher hashedCredentialsMatcher = new HashedCredentialsMatcher();
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashAlgorithmName("MD5");
        hashedCredentialsMatcher.setHashIterations(2);
        return hashedCredentialsMatcher;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        securityManager.setRealm(myShiroRealm());
        //securityManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager());
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager());

        Map<String,String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/index", "anon");

        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");

        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**", "authc");

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/welcome");
        //Unauthorized;
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/error");        
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);       
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    } 

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(){
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager());
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAAP = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        defaultAAP.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return defaultAAP;
    }

    @Bean
    public PassThruAuthenticationFilter passThruAuthenticationFilter(){
        return new PassThruAuthenticationFilter();
    }
}
```

And  the Realm

```
public class MyShiroRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
    private static final  Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MyShiroRealm.class);
    @Resource 
    UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) {
        LOGGER.info("AuthorizationInfo doGetAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principalCollection) : "+principalCollection);
        String principal=(String) principalCollection.getPrimaryPrincipal();
        LOGGER.info(principal);
        User user=(User) userService.findUserByName(principal);
        SimpleAuthorizationInfo info = new SimpleAuthorizationInfo();
        for(Role role:user.getRoles()){
            info.addRole(role.getName());
            for(Permission permission:role.getPermissions()){
                info.addStringPermission(permission.getName());
            }
        }
        return info;
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) throws AuthenticationException {
        LOGGER.info("AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken authenticationToken) : "+authenticationToken);
        String name=((UsernamePasswordToken)authenticationToken).getUsername();
        User user=userService.findUserByName(name);
        if (user != null) {
          Session session = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getSession();
          session.setAttribute("user", user);
          return new SimpleAuthenticationInfo(name,user.getPassword(),getName());
      } else {
          return null;
      }
    }
}
```

Properties in application.properties

```
#thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

#hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.show-sql= true
#html

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

DB properties are not given. Tomcat's server port is 8080.

The recources dir:
[dir of resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6OY5.png)

When I access the "127.0.0.1:8080/index" ,it redirects to the "error" page setted by

```
  shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/error");.
```

when the "/login" Controller method is given it redirects to login page.

I am so confused and cannot find a way to solve it.

UPDATE

After moving the index.html to templates dir and make a @RequestMapping("/index") method,I get the index in browser.(If the index.html is in the static dir, A @RequestMapping("/index") method don't work.)
How could I get the static html ?

Answer (score 0):

As I test, for the resources in static folder like "/css/**","/index.html" ,

If we want to access them without being intercepted by shiro,

full name like

```
 "127.0.0.1:8080/css/a.css" or "127.0.0.1:8080/index.html",
```

should be used,

which the filterChainDefinitionMap should be setted as

```
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/index.html", "anon");

    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/css/**", "anon");
```